# Cometchat add alt attribute to imgs

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working with cometchat. I want to add the alt attribute to icon `<img>` tag:

```
`<div class="cometchat_trayiconimage">
    <img src="/cometchat/modules/home/icon.png">
</div>`
```

I've found this on cometchat.js. It seems a function that "constructs" the HTML code.

`<div class=\"cometchat_trayiconimage\"><img alt=\""+_3[x][49]+"\" src=\""+_1+"modules/"+icon[0]+"/icon.png\">`

I've added the alt attribute, but It doesn't work. 
But It seems to me, that the img icon is added on modules/home/code.php

`$trayiconinfo = array('home','Home');
    $trayicondata = 'JHRyYXlpY29uW10gPSBhcnJheSgnaG9tZScsJ0hvbWUnLCcvJywnJywnJywnJywnJywnJyk7';`

The base64 code have diferent parameters, and maybe one of that is for what I need:

`$trayicon[] = array('home','Home','/','','','','','','');`

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: You need to more clear about your question ..

Comment: @AnantDabhi " I want to add the alt attribute to icon images" `<img alt="" src=""/>`